# Why can't this image be seen by this user?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, access, image

I have put several images in `Style Library/Images` and used one of them as the site logo. Certain users cannot see it, getting a broken image icon and the ALT text instead. When I check the permissions for the image, I see these two apparently contradictory statements:

[image]

What do these two statements mean when they appear together?

The users can access other images placed in the `Style Library/Images` folder and I can't see what is different about this image. Where should I look next to figure out what is wrong?

Here is the IIS log produced when trying to access the image - the "Detected a redirection but the redirect is not to a known signin page" bit bothers me, should it?

```
SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://xxx:80/Style%20Library/Images/xxx_logo_180x64.png)). Parent No     
SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://xxx:80/Style%20Library/Images/xxx_logo_180x64.png) 1d85a39d-388b-8081-742d-c5433b7a030c
SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium      Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|xxx\xxxtestuser, ClaimsCount=21  1d85a39d-388b-8081-742d-c5433b7a030c
SharePoint Foundation           General                         af71    Medium      HTTP Request method: GET    1d85a39d-388b-8081-742d-c5433b7a030c
SharePoint Foundation           General                         af75    Medium      Overridden HTTP request method: GET 1d85a39d-388b-8081-742d-c5433b7a030c
SharePoint Foundation           General                         af74    Medium      HTTP request URL: /Style%20Library/Images/xxx_logo_180x64.png   1d85a39d-388b-8081-742d-c5433b7a030c
SharePoint Foundation           Files                           aise3   Medium      Failure when fetching document. 0x80070005  1d85a39d-388b-8081-742d-c5433b7a030c
SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  1d85a39d-388b-8081-742d-c5433b7a030c
SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (PreSendRequestHeaders). Execution Time=16.18688    1d85a39d-388b-8081-742d-c5433b7a030c
SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication           amge7   Medium      SPFederationAuthenticationModule.IsRedirectToLogOnPage: Detected a redirection but the redirect is not to a known signin page: http://xxx/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Fxxx%2FStyle%20Library%2FImages%2Fxxx_logo%5F180x64%2Epng&Type=item&name=cf5a1c26%2D340e%2D4de2%2Dbfc5%2D9f382a10d4bb&listItemId=54  1d85a39d-388b-8081-742d-c5433b7a030c
SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:http://xxx:80/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Fxxx%2FStyle%20Library%2FImages%2Fxxx_logo%5F180x64%2Epng&Type=item&name=cf5a1c26%2D340e%2D4de2%2Dbfc5%2D9f382a10d4bb&listItemId=54)). Parent No   
SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://xxx:80/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Fxxx%2FStyle%20Library%2FImages%2Fxxx_logo%5F180x64%2Epng&Type=item&name=cf5a1c26%2D340e%2D4de2%2Dbfc5%2D9f382a10d4bb&listItemId=54)   1d85a39d-288f-8081-742d-c424cac80588
SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium      Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|xxx\xxxtestuser, ClaimsCount=21  1d85a39d-288f-8081-742d-c424cac80588
SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  1d85a39d-288f-8081-742d-c424cac80588
SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,1 agb9s    1d85a39d-288f-8081-742d-c424cac80588
SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://xxx:80/_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Fxxx%2FStyle%20Library%2FImages%2Fxxx_logo%5F180x64%2Epng&Type=item&name=cf5a1c26%2D340e%2D4de2%2Dbfc5%2D9f382a10d4bb&listItemId=54)). Execution Time=18.6286933333333 1d85a39d-288f-8081-742d-c424cac80588
```

Comment: If it is in the style library, make sure the file is checked in as a major version, published and approved.

Comment: Yes, that was it! I came to the same conclusion after noticing that the image in question had "Publish a major version" in its right-click menu and the other images didn't. Thanks for responding - if you write up your suggestion as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any item having 0 versions published as major will not be visible to all except person uploading it.

Any item having few major versions but latest version as minor (not published as major) then latest version will not be available to users except uploading/modifying the item/document/files

So always publish any resource in case of such issue

Comment: Thanks, Gaurravs. That's essentially what @Eric and I concluded, but I appreciate your confirmation.